# Using SOQL, how can I access the LastTransferDate on the Lead object?

Tags: soql, leads

Whenever I try using a reasonable query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, LastTransferDate, LastActivityDate, 
       LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate, IsUnreadByOwner, OwnerId, Owner.Name 
  FROM Lead
```

I get this error message:

```
INVALID_FIELD:
SELECT Id, Name, LastTransferDate, LastActivityDate
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:18
No such column 'LastTransferDate' on entity 'Lead'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

This is the API name for this field, at least according to the object definition - what am I doing wrong?

> EDIT:
>
> If this is not available from SOQL, what is the next best way to get
>   access to this data?

Comment: Looking at the documentation https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm, I don't see a field called LastTransferData. Is it a custom field?

Comment: No - it appears in setup | customize | lead  | standard fields - I suspect this is one of those sfdc convenience fields that are synthesized at runtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why, but by default this field was disabled on the field level security for default System Administrator profile. I checked the profile and enabled this field, after that the field is available via SOQL

[image]

Comment: Why on earth would SFDC do this!?!? That was the problem - it flat never occurred to me that SFDC would make ONE field on the Lead invisible using FLS to the System Administrator ... why?

Answer (score -1):

Did you run this query in eclipse, I execute this query in Develper console, work bench and I ran into the same error you posted.

But when I tried this in eclipse I didn't get the error. Unfortunatly I did not have data to see the results.

Comment: this isn't really an answer

Comment: I am not able to comment, So I wrote it as a answer. When I try to do a comment it is saying I need 50 Reputation.